# Is context switching is the only factor that affects the bounded waiting in process synchronization?

Tags: operating-system, context-switching

Are there any other factors that affect the property of bounded waiting in process synchronization other than context switching?

Comment: What else could there be?  If there is no thread context change, then the current set of running threads can never change.

Comment: So that means, if there is no context switching there is no bounded waiting?